# How to get HTML Local Storage value in ASP.NET PageLoad event?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

text value am assigning to Local storage like :

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="field medium" ID="TextTreatement" /><br />
 localStorage.setItem("TextTreatementKey", TextTreatement);// here am textbox value assign to local Storage.
```

I have declared Hidden field like :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectTestID" runat="server" /
```

my java script like :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function (){ 
  document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelectTestID.ClientID %>').value = localStorage.getItem("hdntestValue"); }
```

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string val =hdnSelectTestID.Value // here am not able asign value. its coming string.empty 
  }
```

Comment: there value its coming but am not able to get value page load event????

Comment: Are you sure the value is set with JavaScript?

Comment: yes its setting .. i have page Init event also its not assigning ???

Comment: The HiddenField class does not have a `.value` property. Did you mean `.Value`? C# is case sensitive. Also, can you show what context `localStorage.setItem("hdTreatmentText", TextTreatement);` is executing under? Is it really right below your control declarations? Or is it off in a script tag somewhere? Also, are you expecting to read this value when the page first loads, *or after a postback?*

Comment: when the page first loads i need that value ???

Comment: You can't get it then. Keep in mind how web servers and clients work. The server side executes first, *then* sends the resulting HTML/CSS/JS to the client. Therefore, you can't get values from the client side JavaScript before the initial page load. An alternative is to store the info in a cookie, or use AJAX to communicate back to the server, or pick the value up after a postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it on initial page load, which is what it sounds like you want to do. Keep in mind how web servers and clients work. The server side executes first, then sends the resulting HTML/CSS/JS to the client. Therefore, you can't get values from the client side JavaScript before the initial page load. An alternative is to store the info in a cookie, or use AJAX to communicate back to the server, or pick the value up after a postback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a little bit late but I think you are not taking the right aproach, whatever you are trying to do on Page_Load will execute first, thats why that method "cant" find anything, because it hasnt been created yet.

Maybe you sould try using another JS after the page is created so that you can manipulate variables that you have already created and worked with.

Dont know if its the nicest way but maybe you can store whatever you want to manipulate from server on a session variable lets say Session["myvariable"]= "whatever" an then you can use it through js with <%Session["myvariable"]%>